# Using <p> with left floating divs causes second div to go below first div

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/9nh220q2/1/

Basically, I have something like this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bWQUX0O.jpg" class="image" />
      <span>0.3 mi</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h3>TITLE HERE</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec turpis eu mi nullam sodales.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, these items are inside of a scrolling panel.  So, in the jsFiddle I have put these inside of a parent div with width of 600px.  As you can see, the `<div class="right">` is going below.  How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: You've to give your right div a width as well. Typically calculate it from the width of the container and subtract the left div width and the padding. See here - **https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/9nh220q2/5/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculated width of .right

`.right {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}`

```css
.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin: 0;
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 100px - 20px);  /* all width - size of image - padding) */
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 600px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bWQUX0O.jpg" class="image" />
      <span>0.3 mi</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h3>TITLE HERE</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec turpis eu mi nullam sodales.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bWQUX0O.jpg" class="image" />
      <span>0.3 mi</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h3>TITLE HERE</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec turpis eu mi nullam sodales.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bWQUX0O.jpg" class="image" />
      <span>0.3 mi</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h3>TITLE HERE</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec turpis eu mi nullam sodales.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by removing all `float` and using `flexbox`. Flexbox is a powerful modern way to handle this kind of layout. [flexboxfroggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) is a great way to learn about them.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9nh220q2/6/)

An even better way would be to use standard css grid, but [we should wait a bit more](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

Edit:

All modern browser support [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). For old one, you can use a polyfill if you have to.

Comment: Thanks.  Is flexbox supported in more browsers?  I know I read somewhere that it causes issues on IE.

Comment: @user1354934 I added a caniuse link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `width` of `.right` to a maximum of `440px`. [See the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nh220q2/8/).

**Explanation:**

Your container `div` has a `width` of `600px`. For the elements contained within to line up properly, their `width`s must add up to a **maximum** of `600px`.

Your `img` already takes up `100px` of that. That means that your `div.right` can have a maximum `width` of `500px`. (Because `600px - 100px = 500px`)

However, if you do set it at `500px`, you'll most likely notice that the issue won't be solved. This happens because, by default, most (*if not all*) browsers render the page using the `content-box` model which **includes** the `padding` and `margin`s of the elements when calculating their `width`s.

In your case, your containing `div` has `20px` of `padding` in both sides. In addition, your `div.right` has `20px` of `padding` on the left. This adds up to `60px` which you need to subtract from your available space that we calculated above, `500px`. That leaves you with `440px` and if you set that as the `width` of `div.right`, you'll notice that the elements line up perfectly!

You can also change the default way in which the browser sees the box model by changing the value of `box-sizing` from `content-box` to `border-box` (neither `padding` nor `margin`s are not calculated in `width`) or to `padding-box` (`padding` is not calculated in `width`) and then adjust `padding`, `border` or `width` values accordingly.

Comment: [The asker isn't new to asking questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1354934/user1354934?tab=questions) I really don't think that link is necessary. In fact, the asker might even find it patronizing.

Comment: OK, I removed it. Thanks for the comment. I added it because I answered a question before and the asker acknowledged that I had solved their problem yet didn't mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: With that said, do you think it's good practice to include that when the asker is inexperienced? I read a few threads here at SO about that and the general consensus was positive.

Comment: Never include it in the body of an answer. You can prompt a new user in the comments as a response to their saying thanks, but make sure they're actually new - otherwise your comment might rub someone the wrong way.

Comment: OK, thanks again. I did include it in the comments on my other answer but to no avail.